# How to set default format for converting date to string?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB I store date in a field with type Date and it look like:

```
startDate: 2019-12-14T09:00:00.000+00:00
```

I need that DB returns date in next format: `2019-12-14T09:00:00` (without "Z" at the end) to avoid of applying to date a timezone shifting during execution `new Date('2019-12-14T09:00:00Z')` in a browser. For this purpose in `$project` I use `$dateToString` operator:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {'startDate': {'$gte': new Date(fromDate)}}
  },
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 0,
      'startDate': {$dateToString: {format: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', date: '$startDate'}}
    }
  }
]);
```

I'd like to avoid of specifying `$dateToString` operator in each request to DB where I'm going to retrive date. I'm looking for something like this:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, dateToStringFormat: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'})
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/GCKM00vSWzk/RfbrMKFKBAAJ) of MongoDB staff in Google Groups:

> I don’t believe this is possible to do in MongoDB as it currently stands. Date without a timezone would be ambiguous, and especially tricky if you have to deal with daylight savings time. Having Z at the end of the timezone unambiguously refer to a single point in time in UTC.
>
> Removing the timezone component from Date would deprive it of a crucial information regarding the exact moment of time that is consistent across timezones and daylight savings time. Unfortunately you would need to either use the $dateToString or remove the timezone component in the client side if your use case mandates it.